# Performance comparison of dual core and quad core processors with same TDP

Tags: cpu, watts, core

Athlon X2 340 (dual core) and Athlon X4 740 (quad core) from AMD have same architecture and both have same TDP (65W).  They also have roughly similar frequency.  Does this means that at full load, the quad core processor is more efficient in calculations/watt than the dual core processor?

I know that TDP is not max power consumption.  For the above processors, at peak load, I would expect dual core to use roughly half the power to that of a quad core, but doesn't the same TDP mean that the dual core and the quad core processors will have similar power consumption at peak load?

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: Sure.  Will ask them too.

Answer (score 1):

A fact is that the 'cores' (or pipeline) are only a small portion of the CPU. If you open up a CPU you will notice that more than half of the 'real-estate' is spent on cache. There are many other parts that exists both on quad core and dual core CPUS and I will let you on a small secret, on many dual-core CPU chips there are actually 4 cores, 2 are disabled. Why is that? many times it is because there are production errors on some of the CPU sections (You really didn't think that they can print billion transistors with no errors did ya) and on some cases cores are just disabled due to marketing decision as it is cheaper to disable a core or two than to set up another production line.

Comment: This does not really answer any of the questions though, it's more suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

TDP for such low end CPUs is often highly exaggerated. It's hard to find proper benchmarks for a CPU such as Athlon x2 340, but I suspect that even at full load it won't require 65 watts worth of cooling(what TDP really means is a whole another topic).

Another factor is binning. The Athlon x4 has 4 fully functional cores, and it's verified to run within spec. The Athlon x2 has two enabled cores, but it's made from the same dies as the Athlon x4, just with 2 cores disabled. Why? One or both of those cores could be damaged, or it could be that it simply couldn't meet the spec for the Athlon x4 because it requires higher voltage to stay stable at the same frequency. So it could, indeed, be running less efficiently.

Finally, as Gilad points out, the CPU isn't all cores, it also has integrated memory controller, I/O such as PCI-e lanes, and so on. So yes, the dual-core will indeed be less efficient in terms of performance/watt, but likely not by nearly as much as the TDP would imply.